# Two divs refuse to be on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file containing an image, underneath this image I want to display two divs on the same line like this:

```
text1                       text2
```

But no matter how I try it, it turns out looking like this:

```
text1
text2
```

This is quite annoying.

```
 <div id="footer">  
                {% block footer %}      
                    <div class="footercontent">                 
                        <div class="left">&copy; blahblahblah </div>

                        <div class="right">
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://privacy.aol.com/">Privacy</a>
                            |   
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://legal.aol.com/TOS">Terms of Use</a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>              
                 {% endblock %}
            </div>
```

I want the two inner divs to dwell on the same line and to display this way on all modern browsers. To do this I have set a css file as such:

```
#footer                 { margin:auto;   width:720px; }
#footer a               {   color:#333;         }   
#footer a:visited       {   color:#333;         }
#footer .left           {   float:left;         }   
#footer .right          {   float:right; }
```

Am  I missing something obvious here? I though float was meant to solve this issue.

**EDIT:** It seems to appear correctly in Chrome

Comment: Yes, the `width`. If they are both 100% wide they cannot be in the same line, even if floated. Make them 50% like `#footer .left, #footer .right: 50%`. For seeing where each div a small trick I do is to give each a different background to know where they are actually (:

Comment: Where is `#footer .left` in your HTML?

Comment: Or much better, use a browser with decent developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) in Mozilla or Chrome.

Comment: Apologies, I was messing with the HTML earlier and forgot to add it back in.

Comment: This seems to work fine in Firefox 31 and Chrome 39..... what browser are you using specifically?

Comment: Does the template variable ` {% block footer %} ` add any additional HTML/CSS to the layout?

Comment: Francisco, it turns out your answer solved the issue and now it displays correctly for all browsers. If you add yours as an answer, I will gladly mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as posted, actually works as shown below.

If you use `float: right`, the second child block will have its right edge aligned to the right of the containing block.

If you want the second block to be towards the left, use `float: left` as shown in the second example, and add a left margin if you need to control spacing between the two elements.

If you still have problems, there may be some other CSS rules that are causing a conflict.

```css
.footer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px; /* for demo only, exact value not relevant */
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer a {
  color: #333;
}
.footer a:visited {
  color: #333;
}
.footer .left {
  float: left;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.footer .right {
  float: right;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.left.space {
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<h2>First layout...</h2>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footercontent">
    <div class="left">&copy; blahblahblah</div>

    <div class="right">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://privacy.aol.com/">Privacy</a>
      |
      <a target="_blank" href="http://legal.aol.com/TOS">Terms of Use</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Second layout...</h2>
 <div class="footer">
  <div class="footercontent">
    <div class="left">&copy; blahblahblah</div>

    <div class="left space">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://privacy.aol.com/">Privacy</a>
      |
      <a target="_blank" href="http://legal.aol.com/TOS">Terms of Use</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set display property of anchor tag like

```
#footer a {
color:#333; 
display:inline-block
}
```